# aws iam - Role Policy for MFA

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I am having a hard time to understand the difference between:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::123456:root"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Condition": {
        "Bool": {
          "aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent": "false"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

VS

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::123456:root"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
    }
  ]
}
```

With the 1st policy, my IAM user in the management account is unable to assume role and authenticate to the **123456** account, but with the 2nd policy it works.

My understanding is that having `aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent`set to **false** should behave same is when there is no condition for it, but it works differently.

Answer (score 1):

I think `"aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent": "false"` is explicitely forbidding to use a MFA token to assume this role via `sts`. Probably not what you want

- `"aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent": "true"` on the other hand, will explicitely require that the user is logged with a MFA token before being allowed to assume this role